# quality vs inequality contraints for Large scale LP

Tags: performance, math, linear-programming

Inequality vs equality constrains.
Is there a big computational advantage by explicitly converting your problem to standard form via slack variables before passing it to solver instead of solver doing it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do any transformation myself. Any reasonable implementation should do the necessary transformations for you automatically, and do it in a way that is the best from the implementation's point of view.

In short, pose your problem the way it is natural for you and leave the rest up to the solver. Even the performance of the solver is likely to be the best this way.

Comment: Good answer. I'll add that many in the optimization community are working hard to reach the level of "pose your problem the way it is natural for you and leave the rest up to the solver" for a large class of optimization problems, in which the solver does complex transformations between different problem classes automatic. See for example the Reformulation and Optimization Software Engine (ROSE).

Comment: @raoulcousins Yes, I know it's not like "pose your problem the way it is natural for you and leave the rest up to the solver" *in general* but I am pretty sure that manually introducing the slack variables is not going to improve the performance. In fact, it is even likely to make things worse as most solvers introduce slack variables anyway...

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should be able to pose your problem the way it is natural for you and leave the rest up to the solver in general. We're not there yet, but we're moving towards it. It's all just a form of premature optimization if you don't throw it to the solver before doing anything else.